# Delete all files of a directory in Firebase storage on Firestore document delete

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
exports.deleteItemImages = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}')
    .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
        const deletedValue = snap.data();
        const id = deletedValue.id;

        if (id === null) {
            return null;
        }

        console.log(`itemId to be deleted: ${id}`);

        bucket.deleteFiles({
            prefix: '${id}/'
        }, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(`Successfully deleted images with item id: ${id}`);
            } else {
                console.error(`Failed to remove images, error: ${err}`);
            }
        });
    })
```

I have a collection `items` with each document having a field `id`. Each document has images associated with it, stored in Firebase storage in a directory (folder) by the same folder name `id`. I want to remove each `id` folder in Firebase storage when its respective Firestore document is deleted. In my Firebase cloud functions log, the line `console.log(`Successfully deleted images with item id: ${id}`);` is successfully printing but the folder deletion is not happening

EDIT: I tried manually putting in a folder name for `prefix: '${id}/'`, and it worked. So it is not an issue with connecting to Firebase storage, but rather with that line in particular..

Comment: Just realized my issue. I had written the prefix line with single quotes, not backticks

Answer (score 1):

NVM. The line

`prefix: '${id}/'`

Should be backticks, not single quotes

-__-